# x and y are not the same size for graphing. And need text inside graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num1 = 30
num3 = [4000,3000,1500,9000,2500,8000,1200,800,900,1000,5400,9500,1100,3400,8100,
        5500,1200,3830,2311,9999]
#num3_array = []
num2_array = []
for i in range (0,20):
    num2 = random.randrange(0,45)
    print(num2)

#num3_array.append(num3)
num2_array.append(num2)

plt.axvline(num1,0,color="r")
plt.scatter(num2_array,num3,marker=",")
```

I want to have num2 values on the x-axis and their corresponding num3 values on y-axis. I don't know how to get it. I keep getting an error.

```
ValueError: x and y must be the same size
```

I know what it means. I just don't know how to fix it.

Also, I need text inside the graph. I want to point to the red line and say "num1 = 30", and then count the number of scattered dots on both the left hand and right hand side of the red line, and put the count in the right hand side corner of the graph. On the red line is considered to be on the right hand side.

[image]
The image above is what i created using excel. What I need is that box in the RHS corner using matplotlib. That box has the count of dots on LHS and RHS.

Answer (score 0):

The first change I would make to this program would match up the length of y values with the length of 'x' values, which can allow you to begin graphing:

```
num2 = []
for i in range (len(num3)):
    num2.append(random.randrange(0,45))
    print(num2)
plt.plot(num2, num3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That is part of it. I changed "plt.plot" to "plt.scatter" because that is what shows points. Now, what about the next part ?

Comment: Here is a link that explains a bit more about annotation in matplotlib: [link]http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html

Comment: I guess a line like this: `plt.annotate(num1, xy=(num1, 11000), xytext=(10, 5),
            arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black', shrink=0.05),
            )` But I want to have "num 1 = 30" That 30 should be read from num1 = . And I don't want the arrow to be so long. Just want a clean image. Instead of saying "11000", I just want it to be almost at the top, but not touching. And what about the count ?

Comment: if it is going to be too messy, then don't worry the annotate part. I just want the count.

Answer (score 0):

In order to plot a scatter graph from `x` and `y` coordinate iterables the two iterables have to have the same length. If the `x` iterable is longer than the `y` then what `y` coordinate should the extra `x` values be given (and vice versa)?

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

num1 = 30
num3 = [4000,3000,1500,9000,2500,8000,1200,800,900,1000,5400,9500,1100,3400,8100,
        5500,1200,3830,2311,9999]

num2_array = []
for _ in num3:
    num2 = random.randrange(0,45)
    print(num2)
    num2_array.append(num2)

plt.axvline(num1,0,color="r")
plt.scatter(num2_array,num3,marker=",")
plt.show()
```

This now works fine, however numpy gives us a better (faster, clearer etc) way of doing it with the [numpy.random.random_integers](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.random_integers.html#numpy.random.random_integers) function.

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num1 = 30
num3 = [4000,3000,1500,9000,2500,8000,1200,800,900,1000,5400,9500,1100,3400,8100,
        5500,1200,3830,2311,9999]

num2_array = np.random.random_integers(0,45,len(num3))

plt.axvline(num1,0,color="r")
plt.scatter(num2_array,num3,marker=",")
plt.show()
```

To count the points on the left hand side of the red line you can simply do something like:

```
count = 0
for value in num2_array:
    if value <= num1:
        count += 1
```

To write this count on the plot you need to look into matplotlib's various methods for [annotating plots](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html). You can use the `text` method to draw the count text, and tell matplotlib to use the axes coordinate system so it always gets drawn in the top left. You'll also need the annotate function to draw your annotation with the arrow. A complete example is below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.anchored_artists import AnchoredText

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

num1 = 30
num3 = [4000,3000,1500,9000,2500,8000,1200,800,900,1000,5400,9500,1100,3400,8100,
        5500,1200,3830,2311,9999]

num2_array = np.random.random_integers(0,45,len(num3))

count = 0
for value in num2_array:
    if value <= num1:
        count += 1

ax.axvline(num1,0,color="r")
ax.scatter(num2_array,num3,marker=",")

ax.text(x=0.85,y=0.95,s="Count: {}".format(count), transform=ax.transAxes)
ax.annotate("Text", xy=(num1, max(num3)/2), xytext=(num1*1.2, (max(num3)/2)*1.2), arrowprops=dict(facecolor='black'))
plt.show()
```

Comment: I need to use matplotlib. Could you help me with the next part?

Comment: Let's just worry about the count. Your code is giving me 0 count.

Comment: @BobH. Have you copied the code exactly as I have it in the final "code block"? For me it gives [this](http://i.imgur.com/hhah1pf.png).

Comment: Yes, I have. Honestly, I can only use matplotlib since the original code I have is structured such that if I want to graph something, then it has to be matplotlib. My original code is much more complex that this. I truly appreciate your effort. You have done a lot on here. If you tweak it to be only matplotlib, then that will be great! I have tried, but I didn't get it because I am new to python, and illustration for all the other projects haven't been the key, so didn't ever really use it. Right now, since I can't get it use to matplotlib, I am just trying to get a count underneath the graph.

Comment: The num1 and num3 you have are fine, but num2 is what is using numpy, and that won't work for me.

Comment: @BobH. The only code that is graphing anything in the sample I gave is matplotlib (pyplot is part of matplotlib). Numpy is a separate library for doing useful things with arrays (this is the very least of what it does). Numpy is a dependency of matplotlib so it should definitely be available if matplotlib is.  When you say numpy "won't work" what exactly happens? Do you get an error message? Why do you think it is numpy which isn't working?

Comment: I got the ax.text to work without numpy :) Now, what you have for the annotate line, I am getting that too, but my arrow is so small and it looks weird, and I want to have "num1 = 30" instead of having "text", and that 30 can't be brute forced. It needs to be pulled from num1 = Also how do I make that graph popup in a new windows because the text is very small

Comment: Okay. My arrow is good too now. The only thing I need beside the arrow is "num1 = 30"

Comment: Look up python string formatting. Its exactly the same as I had in the `s="Count: {}".format(count)` above.

Comment: I don't want to worry about that anymore. The last thing I need is for the graph to pop-out in a separate window.

Comment: It should do that by default with standard python. Are you using ipython or something? I'm not sure how much I can help if you don't even want to learn how string formatting works...its one of the most basic things in any language.